# Complex depth sorting issue based on MC location

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, sorting, depth

I need help rescuing a project concerning some extreme depth management. We're out of ideas!

The project concerns stacking boxes of various sizes, each box is isometric - so thats where the depth comes in to play (we need to weave this box in front of that box, but on top of two boxes and below another, etc - anything goes!)

Here's the project as it stands:

http://clearlytrained.com/depth/

You can drag the boxes then let go over the grid if the grid space is green - if you were to take the two boxes that are one grid space high, place then next to eachother, then take a wider box (2x2) and place it over both (so the gap in the two lower boxes is in the middle of the box you placed on top) you'll see that the far right lower box's depth is now higher and above the box on top. I completley understand why this happens, but no matter how we sweep through the grid in order, this will happen to some extent the way it currently stands.

The way we're currently sorting depth, is sweeping through the grid array, which stores the name of every box on screen, based on the direction we sweep through the rows and columns we get an order to which we then set each box's depth. The problem is that even though a box might take up 6 grid spaces, we don't set the depth 6 times - we only set it the first time we come to its instance name in the array - so if we're sweeping through the grid bottom to top, left to right, a box that's physically under another box, yet further to the right will always have a higher depth. not good!

The only way i can see to fix this is to figure out some sort of box to box comparison of first X then Y values, setting up some sort of double for loop/if statemenet conditions, and more or less, programatically hand place each boxe's depth every time we move or place a new box.  So the complexity goes from setting depth by order of box instance name, to comparing this box to every other box, then every other box to every other box, and coming up with the real order we need to stack their depth. In some cases we might go left to right, then bottom to top, then back to left to right - there's no smooth pattern.

Please play around with the link provided, let me know if you have any other questions or need more info, I'm desperate!

Answer (score 0):

I would add all boxes to an array and sort that by both X and Y value (tile X and Y). It's not a large set, so you don't really have to worry about performance.

Sort by X, then if X is the same, sort by Y. That shoooould solve it, unless I missed something obvious.

Comment: We thought of that - the problem is some boxes might be 3 grid spaces wide - so that 3x wide box and a 1x1 wide box on top of it would both register as having the same X position - the second we get into another column based on X value (being the first condition to check) we'll have already screwed up and placed something over top that 3x wide box. SO, the depth would work well for boxes stacked on top of eachother - but we already have that working more or less and doesn't solve the issue.   This is where I think we need to some how check everything with everything else.. sigh

Comment: Hmm. Yes, I think I see what you mean. What about if you were to set the draw order by which tiles they occupy, starting from the top right, and going out in a "concentric" pattern? Like this: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/340238/Screen%20shot%202011-10-05%20at%205.56.16%20PM.jpg  It's probably not optimal, but I can't think of other ways at the moment. The numbers is the reversed draw order. Eg, 1 on top of everything else. You would also have to remember which boxes has been "used" already (found in a tile), so you don't add them twice.

Comment: Thanks - but the same issue happens - if 1 were starting in the lower left, then we go concentric from there, the last grid space, say number 4, would be set last.. if 4 were on the bottom it's depth would be higher than a box above it - we tried merging this with the x/y position for loop but ran into the same issues.. It's funny how easy it is to see the issue, but we just can't convert that into a function/code!

Comment: Damn, yeah, I found a few cases where it would not work as well. Hmm. Ok, next idea! For every box, keep a list of which adjacent tiles it should cover. Then, for every block, check if there is a block in one of those positions - if there is, insert the testing box above the tested box. You would need to keep an array with all the boxes, where the index equals the order to be displayed. If you make sure you don't move the relative order of the other boxes when you insert it (eg by inserting it above the one tested, but below the one that is above that), it should work. I hope.